# Downcast instance using its type

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a method which uses a generic parameter and requires the downcasted form of the instance. For example,

```
public abstract class Animal {
}
public class Dog : Animal {
}
public class Cat : Animal {
}
public class AnimalHandler {
    public virtual void Pet<T>(T animal)
    {
    }
}
```

Given a collection of animals.

```
public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
```

How do I downcast individual animals before calling the **Pet** method?

I currently having working in this form.

```
if (animal is Dog) {
    _animalHandler.Pet((Dog)animal);
}
if (animal is Cat) {
    _animalHandler.Pet((Cat)animal);
}
```

Ideally, it would be something of this form.

```
var type = animal.GetType();
_animalHandler.Pet(animal.CastTo(type));
```

**Clarification:** I need the instance to be of the downcasted type before it is passed to the method. I need a Dog or Cat specifically to be passed in.

Comment: typeof only works with class names or generics I believe.

Comment: In your AnimalHandler, why is it important that a Dog be seen as a Dog and not an Animal? The object *is* a dog, but why must you know it? What's being done in this Pet method? Keep in mind, the method can make no assumptions on T other than what constraints might reveal.

Comment: it's usually(not always) bad practice for a generic method, to do stuff with it's type parameters. it makes it... less generic...

Comment: @Anthony, because we are using a generic inteface to an NHibernate repository and the generic type will determine which mapping (and table) the query runs against.

Comment: @AK_, I agree. However, due to a limited table structure, we have to downcast before making the database call even though we are not using any properties on the downcasted type.

Comment: @Ty, then you have some difficulty. You cannot create a `CastToActual()` method, because what would it return? The dog, yes, but not *as* a Dog. The signature would simply need to be `Animal CastToActual()`. You might need to explore a double dispatch pattern, perhaps Visitor.

Comment: @Ty - Fixed my answer. It should reflect what you're after now.

Comment: @Ty. use NHibernate, Generic Dao is a very well known pattern.
anyway when writing code that depends on the type you should use typeof/reflections internally. nothing generic about that.

Comment: @Ty. also a return value of void, also might imply you shouldn't use generics. might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the new .NET 4 `dynamic` keyword:

```
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
    public abstract class Animal {
    }
    public class Dog : Animal {
    }
    public class Cat : Animal {
    }
    public class AnimalHandler {
        public virtual void Pet<T>(T animal) {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
        }
    }

    public class Problem {
        public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
        private readonly AnimalHandler _animalHandler;

        public Problem(AnimalHandler animalHandler) {
            _animalHandler = animalHandler;
            Animals = new List<Animal> { new Cat(), new Dog() };
        }

        public void MakeDecision() {
            foreach (var animal in Animals) {
                 _animalHandler.Pet(animal);
            }
        }
    }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
            animals.Add(new Dog());
            animals.Add(new Cat());

            var handler = new AnimalHandler();
            handler.Pet((dynamic)animals[0]);
            handler.Pet((dynamic)animals[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the cast to `dynamic` in the calls to `Pet`. Though doing it this way negates the necessity of `Pet` being generic in the first place.

Comment: That would type my collection to one specific instance of Animal. List<Animal<Dog>> for example.

Comment: Dude! It works, that is pretty awesome. Can you update your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Ty. - [This](http://rextester.com/EAE73740) also works and only required one line of code change from your original. `Console.WriteLine(typeof(T))` to `Console.WriteLine(animal.GetType())`. Your animal never needed to be cast in the first place (which was the point of all of the people above)

Comment: I need the typeof(T) to be Cat or Dog, the instance was always correct.

Comment: Ok I'll update my answer to reflect using the dynamic keyword to get what you're after.

Comment: That is much simpler. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

If, as your clarification says, you "Need a concrete `Dog` or `Cat` to be passed in" then your method cannot take a generic `Animal`.

However, what I suspect you're missing is that the `Handler` should not need to know what type of animal it has, only how to Handle that Animal. See this expanded example:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void Speak();
}
public class Dog : Animal {
    public override void Speak(){ Console.WriteLine("WOOF!! You're great."); }
}
public class Cat : Animal {
    public override void Speak(){ Console.WriteLine("Meow. Im better than you."); }
}
public class AnimalHandler {
    public virtual void Pet<T>(T animal) where T : Animal
    {
        animal.Speak();
    }
}
```

When executing this with the following code:

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
animals.Add(new Dog());
animals.Add(new Cat());

var handler = new AnimalHandler();
handler.Pet(animals[0]);
handler.Pet(animals[1]);
```

Im sure you can imagine the output (If not, Live example: http://rextester.com/UJZRB90548). You see from this, I only have a list of Base `Animal`, but when it is passed in to the Handler, the correct method is called.

Comment: This will call the correct method, but the AnimalHandler still receives the instance as a type of Animal. The generic type would still be Animal, unfortunately.

Comment: @Ty - Yup, that's the way it works. If you need a Dog, you cant reference it as an Animal. If you have a list of Animals, you cant cast it to a Dog in any way other than those you already know about.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few alternatives. One approach would be to have sub-classes of `AnimalHandler` per animal type and manually dispatch to the correct one:

```
public class AnimalHandler
{
    public void Pet(Animal animal)
    {
        if (animal is Cat)
        {
            this.catHandler.Pet((Cat) animal);
        }
        else if (animal is Dog)
        {
            this.dogHandler.Pet((Dog) animal);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("animal");
        }
    }

    private readonly CatHandler catHandler;
    private readonly DogHandler dogHandgler;
}
```

As an alternative to all the 'if's and 'is's you could add an `AnimalType` enum property to the `Animal` class and use a `switch` statement.

The above approach could be made a bit more generic and extensible by creating an interface to represent a specific animal type handler:

```
public enum AnimalType
{
    Cat,
    Dog,
}

public interface ISpecificAnimalHandler
{
    AnimalType AnimalType { get; }
    void Pet(Animal animal);
}

public class AnimalHandler
{
     public AnimalHandler()
     {
         var handlers = new ISpecificAnimalHandler[] { new CatHandler(), new DogHandler() };
         this.handlersByAnimal = handlers.ToDictionary(handler => handler.AnimalType, handler);
         // ...
     }

     public void Pet(Animal animal)
     {
         ISpecificAnimalHandler handler;
         if (!this.handlersByAnimalType.TryGet(animal.AnimalType, out handler))
         {
              throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Animal of type " + animal.GetType().Name " not supported.");
         }

         handler.Pet(animal);
     }

     private IDictionary<AnimalType, ISpecificAnimalHandler> handlerByAnimalType;
}

public class CatHandler : ISpecificAnimalHandler
{
    public AnimalType AnimalType
    {
        get { return AnimalType.Cat;
    }

    public void Pet(Animal animal)
    {
        var cat = (Cat) animal;
        // do petting, meow
    }
}
```

Another, different, option is to use dynamic dispatch:

```
public class AnimalHandler
{
    public void Pet(Animal animal)
    {
        PetAnimal((dynamic) animal); // will dispatch to most appropriate method at runtime
    }

    public void PetAnimal(Cat cat)
    {
        // do petting, meow
    }

    public void PetAnimal(Dog dog)
    {
        // do petting, woof
    }
}
```